# How to send email from smtp server1 to smtp server2 (Postfix) via client?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp, relay

How to make server1 with postfix can send email to server2 with postfix by redirecting DNS query to it (type forward). These servers are on the same local network. Server1 is to receive a non-authoritative response from server2 about the serverx.eu domain. Server1 has the a@serverd.com box, and server2 has b@serverx.eu. Server1 cannot have a serverx.eu domain zone and is not a slave server. Server1 has a serverd.com domain zone. The email is to be sent from a client that is on the same local network to the b@serverx.eu mailbox. Server1 should forward this email to server2. The DNS server of the client is server1.

Comment: DNS and Postfix using very different protocols, Postfix is mailserver and thus can't redirect DNS traffic. Postfix operates at SMTP(S) and other mail protocols.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of both servers and the client uses one of them as a mail submission server then use `postfix` [transport maps](https://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) to route the mail, no need to manipulate DNS.